# Parse.com Cloud Code: function called simultaneously by 2 users

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

i'm reviewing all the cloud code i wrote for my app and i already found something i need to correct. I have a parse data base filled with users and "meeting" objects. Every user can create or look and accept a meeting. The next function gets called when a user wants to accept a meeting. If the required number of persons is equal to the number of persons that accepted the meeting become confirmed, else it stays available for other users. Today i tried accepting a meeting simultaneously from 2 client and the meeting didn't get confirmed. Of course the required number of persons was 2. This is the function I'm calling. How can i correct this behavior?

```js
// accept meeting 
Parse.Cloud.define("acceptMeeting", function(request, response) {
 Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
 var userAcceptingTheMeeting = request.user;
 var meetingId = request.params.meetingId;
 var meetingToAccept;
 var userCreatorOfMeeting;
 var changedObjects = [];
 var queryForMeeting = new Parse.Query("MeetingObject");
 queryForMeeting.get(meetingId).then(function(meeting) {
  meetingToAccept = meeting;
  userCreatorOfMeeting = meeting.get("user");
  // incrementing the "acceptedMeetings" number field on the database for the user that accepted the meeting
  userAcceptingTheMeeting.increment("acceptedMeetings", +1);
  changedObjects.push(userAcceptingTheMeeting);
  return changedObjects;
 }).then(function(changedObjects) {
  meetingToAccept.add("participantsObjectId", userAcceptingTheMeeting.id);
  meetingToAccept.add("participantsName", userAcceptingTheMeeting.get("username"));
  // if the length of the array containing all the participants is equal to the number required "meetingNumberOfPersons" then set "isAvailable" to false (the meeting is confirmed)
  if (meetingToAccept.get("participantsObjectId").length === meetingToAccept.get("meetingNumberOfPersons")) {
   meetingToAccept.set("isAvailable", false);
  }
  changedObjects.push(meetingToAccept);
  console.log(changedObjects.length);
  return changedObjects;
 }).then(function(saveChangedObjects) {
  return Parse.Object.saveAll(changedObjects); 
 }).then(function(push) {
  // check if the meeting is still available
  if (meetingToAccept.get("isAvailable") === true) {
   
   // the meeting is still available, send a notification only to the creator of the meeting
   // push to the creator of the meeting 
   
  } else if (meetingToAccept.get("isAvailable") === false) {
   
   // the meeting is confirmed, send notifications to everyone (creator and participants)
   // push to the creator of the meeting 
   
   var participantsArray = [];
   participantsArray = meetingToAccept.get("participantsObjectId");
   participantsArray.splice(participantsArray.indexOf(userAcceptingTheMeeting.id), 1 );
   for (var i = 0; i < participantsArray.length; i++) {
    var participant = new Parse.User({
     id: participantsArray[i]
    });
    
    // push to the other participants 
    
   }
  } 
  return changedObjects; 
 }).then(function(savedObjects) {
  if (meetingToAccept.get("isAvailable") === true) {
   response.success("unconfirmed");
  } else {
   response.success("confirmed");
  }
 }, function(error) {
  response.error("Failed to accept the meeting");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using `.save()` after the `.add()` `meetingToAccept.add("participantsObjectId", userAcceptingTheMeeting.id)`

Consider this sequence of events:

{call 1} acceptMeeting //Begin call 1, participantsObjectId = [] (empty array)

{call 2} acceptMeeting  // Begin call 2, participantsObjectId = []

{call 1} meetingToAccept.add("participantsObjectId", userAcceptingTheMeeting.id)// participantsObjectId = [user1]

{call 2} meetingToAccept.add("participantsObjectId", userAcceptingTheMeeting.id) // t = 2 participantsObjectId = [user2]

{call 1} meetingToAccept.get("participantsObjectId").length check returns 1//participantsObjectId = [user2]

{call 2} meetingToAccept.get("participantsObjectId").length check returns 1

{call 1} Parse.Object.saveAll(changedObjects) // results in participantsObjectId = [user1]

{call 2} Parse.Object.saveAll(changedObjects) // results in participantsObjectId = [user2] **OVERRIDING** participantsObjectId = [user1]

Also, a comment about your code: It becomes more readable if you space the code. so that it's not so dense. Also, I  suggest at each "then" you make a comment about what that "then" does.